# Results of a test in an if/else statement in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a test `this.test.assertExists("blablabla");`.

How do I use the results of this test in an if/else statement?  In other words, I want the program to do one thing if the test passes, and a different thing if it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think tests are intended to work that way. But what you can do is use some of the functions in CasperJS to replicate some if/else statements to do what you want.

For example, you can use the `__utils__` object to check the attributes or get the values of objects in the DOM. Below is sample code for seeing if a check box is checked:

```
function isChecked(selector)
{
    return __utils__.findOne(selector).checked;
}
```

In your example, you can use the `casper.exists` function to see if a selector is present in the DOM:

```
if (casper.exists('#your_selector'))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do a different thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CasperJS provides most `casper.test.assert*` functions as standalone functions `casper.*`.

You can use it like this

```
if (casper.exists("#selector")) {
    casper.test.pass("selector existed");
    // TODO: do something
} else {
    casper.test.fail("selector existed");
    // TODO: do something else
}
```